# How can I read the contents of a text file and check if they're valid or invalid in Java

Tags: java, exception, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm fairly new at programming and programming in Java. Currently I'm learning about Exceptions and how to handle them. In this one lab I am given multiple text files containing numbers in a grid like manner. I was told to use the command-line arguments to run all the files at once.

[The way the text files look (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxqSw.png)

All files are named valid or invalid. The invalid files have some unique error in them that I have to check for. The first line of each text file gives the total number of rows and columns. I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can check the validity of text files: invalid2, invalid5, and invalid7. I can write some bad code that catches the errors in files invalid5 and invalid7 (which I don't want do), but invalid2 is really giving me a hard time. The problem with **invalid2** is that the first line in the file tells me that the grid has **3 rows** and **4 columns**, but the actual grid has **4 rows** and **3 columns**.

[invalid2 text file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZvVe.png)

I am currently trying to break the grids into *individual* rows. My logic (and here is where I want to know if its faulty) is that I'm using a while loop that checks if there is a next line in the text file. If there is, I will increase my row counter (even though I already know how many rows the grid has). I then check if the row counter is bigger than the actual number of rows given which would throw an exception that there are too many rows. If not, I move onto parsing each row of the grid. I use a String "nextLine" that contains all the numbers in that one row of the grid and parse that string with the Scanner "parse". I use a for loop that goes on the same number of times as there are columns (The # given by the file). I then set the variable "num" of type double to get the next double in that string. At this point my program breaks down. I don't know why I'm getting a NoSuchElementException at that line in my code. [Screenshot on Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLxJL.png) I don't really need to do anything with the information I'm reading from the files so the "num" variable is just there to move onto the next number in the row.

I have two questions

1. Why am I getting the NoSuchElementException in that part of my code?
2. Is my logic correct in how I'm trying to check for the validity of each text file?

The output to the console should look something like this:

valid1.dat

VALID

invalid1.dat

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "X"

INVALID

etc...

This is my code:

```
public class FormatChecker {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    for(int n = 3; n < args.length; n++) {              // Loops through command-line arguments
        String fileName = args[n];                      // Sets specific file 
        try {           
            File file = new File(fileName);             // new File from specified file name
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);           // Scanner object to read the new file
            String firstLine = read.nextLine();         // String to hold the first line of the file
            Scanner parse = new Scanner(firstLine);     // Scanner object to parse the first line (reads first line)
            
            int row = parse.nextInt();          // Gets first token from Scanner object 'parse' to get # of rows
            int col = parse.nextInt();          // Gets second token from Scanner object 'parse' to get # of columns
            
            if(parse.hasNext()) {               // Checks if there are more than two tokens (for invalid4.dat)
                throw new GridSizeException("Too many dimensions"); // If yes, throws created exception "GridSizeException"
            } else {                // HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP W/ MY LOGIC!
                int rowCount = 0;                   // Row counter even thought we already know the # of rows
                while(read.hasNextLine()) {         // While loop that loops until the end of the file
                    rowCount++;                     // row count is increased
                    if(rowCount > row) {            // if row counter is > than our given # of rows, we will throw an exception
                        throw new GridSizeException("Too many rows");
                    }
                    String nextLine = read.nextLine();          // String to hold the next line of the file
                    parse = new Scanner(nextLine);              // For parsing that next line
                    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {              // Loops the same # of times as the # of columns
                        double num = parse.nextDouble();        // Move through the String
                        if(j == col-1 && parse.hasNext()) {     // Checks if there are more numbers in that row than expected.
                            throw new GridSizeException("Too many columns");
                        }
                    }                           
                }                       

                System.out.println(fileName);
                System.out.println("VALID");
                System.out.println();
                
            }               
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(fileName);
            System.out.println(e.toString() + " for input string: " + fileName);
            System.out.println("INVALID\n");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(fileName);
            System.out.println(e.toString() + " for input string: " + fileName);
            System.out.println("INVALID\n");
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(fileName);
            System.out.println(e.toString() + " for input string: " + fileName);
            System.out.println("INVALID\n");
        } catch (GridSizeException e) {
            System.out.println(fileName);
            System.out.println(e.toString() + " for input string: " + fileName);
            System.out.println("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have read line with scanner,   use string.split(" ") ( or whatever separates values )

Result of split() is an array of strings and you can

- check for amount of values  with array.length ( and decide thether there is enough values at all, or there is an error )
- convert individual strings to number and catch an exception ( if number is not valid )

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the split method for Strings but using it allowed me to correctly check each file!

Comment: I ended up using the split() method as was suggested and I was able to check the errors for each files.      
`String nextLine = fileScan.nextLine();       
String[] numbers = nextLine.split(" ");       
if(numbers.length < col) {    
 fileScan.close();
throw new GridSizeException("Fewer columns inside grid than expected");
}      
if(numbers.length > col) {    
fileScan.close();
throw new GridSizeException("Too many columns inside grid");
}      
double[] values = new double[col];  
for(int i = 0; i < col; i++) {   
values[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]);
}`